# Netbook using too much CPU

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, compiz, metacity

I did a clean Ubuntu 14.04 install in a samsung N100sp netbook. System specifications are as follows
2GB RAM
Intel Atom CPU N2100 @ 1.60GHz x 2
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe graphics

The default Unity desktop was unbearably slow. So, I switched to GNOME fallback. Its on a usable speed now.

My problem is CPU is about 80-90% when nothing is running. RAM is only at 10-15%.

top processes in terms of CPU usage are
metacity ~30%
gnome system monitor ~30%
ibus-daemon and dbus-daemon ~20%
chromium ~3%

Using Unity clocks 100% CPU all the time with compiz using about 90%

any suggestions to improve CPU usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" is with your graphics stack. Your graphics card does not support 3d, so llvmpipe makes use of your cpu (rather then your gpu).

You have 2 options:

1. Replace the graphics card.
2. Use an alternate desktop. I have a similar card and prefer KDE, but you can try xfce, lxde, enlightenment, fluxbox ...

See http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

Comment: I have a similar old netbook. Lubuntu works far better on it.

Comment: Thanks bodhi.zazen Isn't GNOME fallback a 2d environment? You mean I should start  a fresh installation of KDE?

Comment: @NasriZuhair It will not falll back to 2d, it fals back to llvmpipe , thus the high cpu use ;)

Answer (score 0):

Disable **Ibus** from System Settings >> Language > Input Method>"Change it from ibus to none.

After that, do a `killall ibus-daemon` in terminal.